# Image does not render in IE but works fine in Chrome, FF and Edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

An (jpg) image on my site is working fine in Chrome, FF, Edge, but not IE. I searched and tried a couple of things but no result.

Coping the image address and pasting it into IE works fine so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:-10px;">

          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-8 datasource-container">
            <div class="img-container">
              <a href="/blog">
                <img src="../../static/img/pptx_automation_img2.jpg"/> 
              </a>
            </div>
            <h1 class="title lead">
                <a href="/blog">Presentations</a>
            </h1>

            <div class="subtitle">April 6, 2018</div>

            <div class="more-link"><a href="/blog">Read on →</a></div>
          </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the line below it works...

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-8 datasource-container">
```

Why is that?

Comment: Remove the sibling and parent elements one by one until you find the culprit.

Comment: Not an answer but the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: someone suggested to do it, hence...

Comment: Can you add the related styles to the classes that you are using beside the boostrtrap specific classes? (.datasource-container, .img-container).